# Parse apache log file with java regex

Tags: java, regex, apache, logging

I was trying to parse an apache log file and it was going fine with the following pattern:

```
^([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" (\\d{3}) (\\d+) \"([^\"]+)\" \"([^\"]+)\"[\\W]+
```

However, it breaks with the following log:

```
218.30.103.62 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:11 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Sogou web spider/4.0(+http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07)"\
```

I´m not really experienced with regex and I´m trying almost in an error and trial method, any help would be appreciated. (I know that the d+ it's not supposed to be there but that's pretty much what I know...)

Any ideia? 
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean that "it breaks"? What are you trying to achieve? "Parsing a log file" doesn't really mean anything. Are you trying to extract some specific information from each row or what?

Comment: After `\d{3}` you have `(\d+)`, replace it with `(\d+|-)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ANpzDy/1).

Answer (score 1):

You format is:

```
"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

(see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html))

So your regex will be:

```
"^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[(.+?)\\] \\\"(.+?)\\\" (\\d{3}) (\\S+) \\\"(.+?)\\\" \\\"(.+?)\\\"[\\W]+ $"
```

where matching groups are (I use the references as defined in apache docs):

1. %h
2. %l
3. %u
4. %t (without enclosing `[]`)
5. %r
6. %>s
7. %b
8. %{Referer}i
9. %{User-agent}i

Note - your regex is a bit overcomplicated, and the reason it fails is because %b is not always a number - when request returns no bytes it will be `-` instead of `0`.

Comment: You can shorten `[^\\s]+` to `\\S+`.

Comment: @oriberu you are right, seems it's time to go to bed for me :D